# Using another class in WPF C# Project

Tags: c#, wpf

How to make an object of another class in MainClass.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {


        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        myClass obj = new myClass();
        //obj.Show(); //not possible!!


    }

    public partial class myClass
    {
        void Show()
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Now In this project, I can't access Show() method using "obj" object. How do I access method of another Class in this project??

Comment: What you really want to do ?, you're just creating an intance of `myClass` type in `MainWindow`. but what you really wnat ?

Comment: I want to call Show() method in MainWindow class.

Comment: Sorry I am new to WPF. In console application we can call a method of one class from another class using instance. But in WPF i can't do this.

Comment: ...  What happens if you uncomment that line and try it?  What do you mean by "not possible!!"?  That looks to me to almost be textbook "how it's done", except for defining myClass as partial, which in this exact example is unnecessary (I assume in the actual code that's another WPF class you're trying to call, in makes my last statement untrue)

Comment: Compiler doesn't show "obj" instance of myClass.

Answer (score 3):

You must declare Show as a public void to have access to the method.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {


        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            obj.Show(); //and must be inside of a method, function or constructor.

        }

        myClass obj = new myClass();
        //obj.Show(); //not possible beacause is not a public method.!!


    }

    public partial class myClass
    {
        //public method.
        public void Show()
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Man, I was totally overthinking this...  :)

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments I understood that you are new WPF, and confusing some concepts with Console Applications.

In Console Applications, the `Main` method acts as an entry point, and everything in the method is executed in an orderly fashion from top to bottom, unless some function calls are made. Consider the following example.

```
Static void Main(string[] args)
{
   myClass obj = new myClass();
   obj.Show();
}
```

This code is valid because when the Console Application starts it executes from top to bottom. I mean it creates a myClass object and calls Show method, but in WPF it's different. The only method that executes immediately like `Main` is `MainWindow` Constructor. The code after the constructor is not auto executed, unless they are properties, just like a Console Application. I mean the following code will not work properly in a console application.

```
Static void Main(string[] args)
{
   myClass obj = new myClass();
}
obj.Show();
```

It's because Show method is called out side of the `Main` method and the program doesn't know what to do with it. Similarly in WPF, you have to call the Show method in the constructor.

```
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    obj.Show();
  }
```

There are many ways to call Show method in WPF, and the above mentioned way is only one of them. The logic Console Applications and Logic of WPF Applications are similar and different at the same time. I suggest you read a few articles or books on WPF to clear things up.